# Why do they don't have OR Why do they not have?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Between these two,

> Why do young people **don't have** good manners?
>
> Why do young people **not have** good manners?

Which is correct? or both are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

> Why do young people not have good manners?

or:

> Why don’t young people have good manners?

If you were making a declaration (as in a title) instead of asking a question, you could say:

> Why young people don't have good manners.

Comment: Note that the question has been edited since your answer and that your parenthetical comment no longer makes any sense. (You might want to just remove it.)

Answer (score 0):

> Why do young people not have good manners?

is correct. You cannot use the word **do** and **don't** in the same sentence in this context as the latter is derived from the former.

The word **not** describes the word **do**. You cannot use the word **don't** to describe **do**